# Vundle is not working on Mac OS X lion

Tags: vim, plugins, osx-lion

So I am pulling my hair out ...

I tried to install [vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle) on Mac OS X Lion(10.7.4) without any luck.

First I tried it on built-in vim it gives me the following error:

> Error detected while processing /Users/username/.vimrc:line    5:
>
> E117: Unknown function: vundle#rc

I tried vundle on a fresh installed vim from source (vim 7.3) didnt work. Then I tried it out on MacVim it didn't work either. They all prompt the same error.

Vundle used to work fine on my Fedora machine.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: I have also tried version 7.3.556 (from https://code.google.com/p/vim/) with no luck

Comment: Can you show us `.vimrc:line 5`?

Comment: Where and how did you install vundle?

Comment: @kev: My .vimrc is exactly like the readme in https://github.com/gmarik/vundle . so my line 5 : call vundle#rc()

Comment: @romainl: the installation is exactly like https://github.com/gmarik/vundle

Comment: With this `set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/` before?

Answer (score 1):

are you calling:

`:filetype off`

directly before:

`:set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle`

(notice lack of trailing space after /vundle)?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this will be very helpful to you.

http://c7.se/switching-to-vundle/